# Expand table view cell height based on it's contents/

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have 2 labels on the cell. If the labels show just one line of text, then the cell looks fine. But if there is more text and if the lines on the labels are wrapped up, then the labels/text on it goes outside of the cell. Attaching image.

[image]

***My current code:***

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {      
    return 68.0
}

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
     // Code to dequeue reusable cell.
    
            self.titleLabel.text = "This is a very very long text for the title label. Testing testing"
            self.subTitleLabel.text = "This is a very very long text for the sub title label. Testing testing the wrapping"
            
            self.titleLabel.sizeToFit()
            self.titleLabel.layoutIfNeeded()
            
            self.subTitleLabel.sizeToFit()
            self.subTitleLabel.layoutIfNeeded()
    }
```

***Solution I tried to fix it:***

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {      
        return UITableView.automaticDimension
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
     // Code to dequeue reusable cell.

            self.titleLabel.text = "This is a very very long text for the title label. Testing testing"
            self.subTitleLabel.text = "This is a very very long text for the sub title label. Testing testing the wrapping"

            self.titleLabel.sizeToFit()
            self.titleLabel.layoutIfNeeded()

            self.subTitleLabel.sizeToFit()
            self.subTitleLabel.layoutIfNeeded()
    }

override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.tableView.delegate = self
        self.tableView.dataSource = self
        self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 500
        self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension
}
```

This is how it looks with the solution. How do I update the height of the cell based on it's contents?

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using Auto Layout in UITableView for dynamic cell layouts & variable row heights](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18746929/using-auto-layout-in-uitableview-for-dynamic-cell-layouts-variable-row-heights)

Comment: did you set `titleLabel` and 1subTitleLabel`
 height constraint ? ??

Comment: PLease set height of Labels. This will fix your problem.

Answer (score 0):

1. set number of lines to zero.
   apply proper constraints.
2. second solution
   put the labels in stackView and number of lines of both labels to zero.